# Rails mysql wants to update column with table rather than row

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm trying to update a user record, I first find the user by id by
`u = u.find_by_id(data['id'])` (the `data` is from an external post request that has been parsed json)

the fetch is successful, then I want to update by the params from `data` by

```
def update_user(data)

  u = User.find_by_id(data['id'])
  u.update(
      email:        data['email'],
      first_name:   data['first_name'],
      last_name:    data['last_name']
      )
```

doing this is  returns the error

`Error: Unknown column 'users.' in 'where clause': UPDATE` users`SET`id`= 0,`updated_at`= '2020-07-18 16:35:28' WHERE`users``` .`` = 0) ```

and

`ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'users.' in 'where clause': UPDATE` users`SET`email`= 'test@test.com',`updated_at`= '2020-07-18 16:30:23' WHERE`users``` .`` = 34347603): ```

I see that it's trying to update the column with the table name rather than the params of the row or the fetched user above (by `u`)

What am I doing wrong or how can I fix it? (this is using mysql2)

User migration

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :users, {:id => false, :primary_key => :id} do |t|
      t.bigint   :id, :unique => true
      t.string    :email
      t.string    :first_name
      t.string    :last_name

      t.datetime  :created_at
      t.datetime  :updated_at
    end
  end
end
```

User model

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
end
```

Comment: Added model and migration

Comment: I want to keep 1 id column that I'm getting from API, but it's working cause that's how the user was fetched anyways?

Comment: Just give it a different name -- active record is not going to play nicely with this set up. It doesn't know how to build the query.

Comment: Alright, I will try that, thanks!

Comment: Yep, that seemed to fix it. thanks! I guess I didn't like having 2 IDs but if that seems to be the convention or  best for active record, then yea

Comment: Try do search like this: User.find_by(id: data['id']) or User.find(data[id'])